# Visual Basic Like Wild Card

Tags: vb.net, ssis, datarow

I am building SSIS package with Script Task in it.

There is this row:

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dsUnsorted.Tables(0).[Select]("FileName like '*.csv'", "FileDate ASC")
```

This one works OK.

But I need to change it to:

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dsUnsorted.Tables(0).[Select]("FileName like 'sales*.csv'", "FileDate ASC")
```

where the `like` command should be `'sales*.csv'` and not `'*.csv'` only. When I have made the change, the Script Task encounters an error.

How should I write it correctly?

[Source](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.cz/2011/04/how-to-configure-foreach-loop-container.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the like statement used in data tables select only allows wildcards at the start and end of the string you are trying to filter on.

So for me being used to like statements in MS SQL server you would think that your code of:

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dsUnsorted.Tables(0).[Select]("FileName like 'sales*.csv'", "FileDate ASC")
```

Would be correct.

However, you need to actually split the comparisons to check the beginning and end of the field you are checking.

*Correct* way to accomplish the task is to add an and statement to check the beginning and the end of the field as that is the only place the wildcard is allowed.

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dsUnsorted.Tables(0).[Select]("FileName like '*.csv' and FileName like 'sales*'", "FileDate ASC")
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it afterwards too :)